# Is it possible to skip input samples with MTAudioProcessingTap?

Tags: ios, audio, core-audio

I'm trying to implement a simple gap removal algorithm using MTAudioProcessingTap.

Within my `process()` function, I'm calling `MTAudioProcessingTapGetSourceAudio()` to retrieve audio. However, if I remove a gap, I need to retrieve *more* audio in order to fill the output buffer, and calling `GetSourceAudio()` again seems to give me exactly the same input audio.

If I return less than `numberFrames` out of `process()`, iOS fills the gaps with silence, which doesn't suit my application - I want to advance time.

If I retrieve less than `numberFrames` frames out of `GetSourceAudio()`, it only returns the first n frames - never the later ones.

So:

- Is there any way to get an MTAudioProcessingTap to skip time? Is it really a one-sample-in-one-sample-out type deal?
- If you can't request extra data from `GetSourceAudio()`, and not retrieving all of the audio will cause gaps in your output, what's the point of letting you ask for a specific number of frames? Further, why do we even need to call `GetSourceAudio()` if the parameters must always be exactly as specified in the `process()` arguments?

---

Update 30 Sep: I've switched over to TheAmazingAudioEngine, which is happy to give me as much audio as I care to ask for. However, I am still puzzled by the design of MTAudioProcessingTap.

Comment: I'm looking to do that same thing. Do you have any examples of how you implemented this? I've used TheAmazingAudioEngine before, but am facing the same issue as your original question.

Comment: A proper reply won't fit in here, but briefly, within the AEAudioControllerFilterCallback I called 'producer' until I had enough data to fill the output buffer: `producer(producerToken, audio, &priv.inputNumFrames)`

Comment: Thanks for the tip. Does this mean you loop through the audio buffer and detect silences and then call `producer` with the a new buffer that omits the silence?

Comment: You need to fill a fixed-size output buffer. `producer` pulls from the input queue. Since we're removing samples (output will be smaller than input), you keep calling `producer` until the output buffer is full. There'll be a bit left over which you retain for the next `filterCallback`.